# Does a summoned creature act immediately after being summoned by a readied action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, readied-action

I have a player that wanted to use a spell to summon a creature if the person in front of him did something hostile using its ready action.

After doing so, he wanted to attack immediately... But it's not his turn anymore since it's a ready action.

The spell is homebrewed, but the summoned creature (like many other summons) share the turn of the summoner.

We settled for an attack spell instead... but what was the right answer? Would he have been able to attack with his summon immediately? Or should he have waited a turn?

Comment: It would be useful to have the description of the homebrew spell.

Comment: Some summoning spells, like elemental summoning, take a minute to complete.  How is this spell worded?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Summoning spells typically define when the summoned creature acts.

For example, *conjure animals* has a sentence that reads:

> Roll initiative for the summoned creatures as a group, which has its own turns.

Now, if the description of your homebrew spell doesn’t have a line like this, *you need to work with your DM to define how the summoned creature(s) relates to the initiative order.*

#### A creature summoned via a readied spell cannot immediately act.

That said, it probably doesn’t matter exactly how it is worded for your particular situation:  **the summoned creature should not get any actions when summoned via the Ready action**. The only thing that was readied was the casting of the spell. For the summoned creature to act on another creature’s turn, it would itself have to have readied an action, and it has not yet had the opportunity to do so by having a turn.

One exception to this would be if *something triggered the summoned creature's available reaction*. For example, if after being summoned, a hostile creature moved out of the summoned creature's reach, the summoned creature could use their reaction to make an opportunity attack.

Another *possible* exception to this would be if the spell description had a provision for the creature to immediately act in some way when summoned, but I’m not aware of any spells that do this. However, we can see an example of what this wording might look like with the spell *spiritual weapon*:

> When you cast the spell, you can make a melee spell attack against a creature within 5 feet of the weapon.

But it should be noted that *spiritual weapon* has a casting time of 1 Bonus Action, so is not eligible to be cast with the Ready action.

Comment: Spiritual weapon has provision for attacking immediately after it's created. Not a creature, but similar enough to consider

Comment: @Mołot I thought about that, I suppose it may be useful to include it as an example of how such a spell might be worded.

Comment: The other common text for summon initiative is in the Summon spells in Tasha's, which all say "In combat, the creature shares your initiative count, but it takes its turn immediately after yours."

Comment: Worth noting (maybe) that a summoned creature does have a reaction, so if an enemy moved out of the reach of the just-summoned creature, it would potentially be able to make an opportunity attack.

Comment: @Marq Good one, I’ll add a note.

Answer (score 7):

### No, it cannot

Using the *Ready* Action allows you to cast the spell using your *Reaction* during **another creature's** turn. You state that the rules of your homebrewed spell are that the summoned creature shares the turn with the summoner and does not roll its own initiative so the earliest it can take an Action is on the next turn of the caster that summoned it. It can use Reactions before that, if it has any, and could perform an opportunity attack if a suitable situation arises but cannot immediately attack with its Action.